# How fix Server Cpanel automatically adds blank lines to the php code file

Tags: php, server, cpanel

After I upload the php file from localhost to hosting, it automatically adds a blank line to my file, every line of code is a blank line.
Even if I upload the .zip file to the hosting site and extract it from the file manager of the hosting server, I still have this situation.

Do you have the same situation I corrected and instructed me.

Sincere thanks !!

Comment: Which IDE you are using?

Comment: I use Sublime Text and hosting Cpanel

Comment: Same problem with me, I'm using phpStorm IDE